# Pygame collision checking lists of hit boxes against each other only checks the last box in the list

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am coding a game in `pygame` and my entity objects have attribute lists of hit boxes.

All the hit boxes are `pygame.rect` objects and when i have them drawn on the screen all of them show up but for some reason the objects only act like they collide if the last hit box in their list collides with the last hit box in the other objects list.

Here is the method I use for the check:

```
def collide_check(self, obj):
    self.update_hit_boxes()
    obj.update_hit_boxes()
    is_collide = False
    if self.can_collide and obj.can_collide:
        for box in self.hit_boxes:
            for obj_box in obj.hit_boxes:
                is_collide = box.colliderect(obj_box)
                if is_collide:
                    break
    else:
        is_collide = False
    return is_collide
```

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here or if this is even possible using only `pygame.rect` objects and `pygame.rect.collide_rect`?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: `break` can exit onlu last (inner) `for`-loop - so it still checks other boxes because it runs outer `for`-loop - and it may set `is_collide = False again. You should use other variable and set `is_collide = True only if other variable is `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it but problem can be because `break` can exit only last/inner `for`-loop - so code still runs outer `for`-loop which can set again `is_collide = False` (because it runs `is_collide = box.colliderect(obj_box)`). And finally it gets `is_collide = True` only if last boxes collides.

You should check collision without assigning to variable and assign variable only inside if`

```
                if box.colliderect(obj_box):
                    is_collide = True
                    break
```

instead of

```
                is_collide = box.colliderect(obj_box)
                if is_collide:
                    break
```

---

Ot put both `for`-loops in separated function and use `return True` instead of `break`

```
def test(obj1, obj2):
    for box1 in obj1.hit_boxes:
        for obj2 in obj2.hit_boxes:
            if box1.colliderect(box2):
                return True
    return False

def collide_check(self, obj):
    self.update_hit_boxes()
    obj.update_hit_boxes()
    is_collide = False
    if self.can_collide and obj.can_collide:
        is_collide = test(self, obj)
    return is_collide
```

---

**EDIT:**

You could use `return` directly in original function

```
def collide_check(self, obj):
    self.update_hit_boxes()
    obj.update_hit_boxes()

    if self.can_collide and obj.can_collide:
        for box in self.hit_boxes:
            for obj_box in obj.hit_boxes:
                if box.colliderect(obj_box):
                    return True

    return False
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a lot, I didn't realize that about break I thought it would exit the entire function

Comment: frankly, you could use `return True` directly in orignial version without external function.